# How to combine 2 array into 1 array using foreach with different key

Tags: php, arrays

I had 2 array with different number of key

First array:

```
 0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'a' => 1
      'b' => 'b'
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'a' => 2
      'b' => '2b'
```

Second array:

```
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'a' => 1
      'c' => 'c'
```

The `'a'` is act like id but there is problem on `'b'` and `'c'` are not mandatory to list out.

I tried `array_merge` before but it quite complex for my next step so i want to know is there others solution for this?

I also tried the `foreach loop` but it stuck at:

```
foreach($first_array as $data){
$result[] = $data;
......
}
```

The output should like this form:

```
[0] => Array
       (
           [a] => 1,
           [b] => 'b',
           [c] => 'c',

       )

[1] => Array
       (
           [a] => 2,
           [b] => '2b',

       )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `'a'` contains the id of the record, it would be a good idea to use this as an identifier in the result array.

```
$results = [];
$dataSets = [$first_array, $second_array];

foreach ($dataSets as $dataSet) {
    foreach ($dataSet as $record) {
        if (!isset($results[$record['a']]) {
            // first occurence of this record
            $results[$record['a']] = $record;
            continue;
        }

        // next occurence of this record, merge it with existing data
        $results[$record['a']] = array_merge($results[$record['a']], $record);
    }
}
```

If the results should be a normal array (e.g. if you want to encode it to JSON and don't want an object), you'll still need to remove the ids at the end

```
$results = array_values($results);
```

Comment: cool answer!! I had stuck at two foreach loop and don't know how to determine if the second set data has no data to match! thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use a multi-dimensional array.
For example:

```
$myarray = array( 
    array("1", "b", "c"), 
    array("2", "2b")
);
```